# Surface where height is a function of two functions, and a sum over the third

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have a function such as:

[image: equation]

Now, I want to make a surface plot of it (matplotlib `plot_surface`). I've constructed the three arrays using `np.arange(stop,end,increment)`.

And here, I'm stuck. I don't want to use a for-loop, since I think I should be able to solve this with `np.sum`.

However, I don't know how to construct the function. Ideally, it can be constructed as `f(x,y,k)` and I'd use `f(x,y) = np.sum(f(x,y,k), k)`.

I am failing to think of the solution.

Comment: You've constructed three arrays for x, y, and f?

Comment: Is the array of `f` an array of functions?  You will also probably benefit from using [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).

Comment: Oh, I can use meshgrid for more than just x,y? So yes, then that'd mean using meshgrid(x,y,k). But then I still need to sum in some way. Also, yes, I made the arrays for x,y and k.

Comment: @wflynny Suppose I use meshgrid(x,y,k) and then define f(x,y,k). How do I then get it to put it in a matplotlib surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather not take a wild guess at what you want to do, but here's an illustrative example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
k = np.arange(1, 11)

# define f_k = (x + y)^k
fk = lambda xx, yy, kk: (xx + yy)**kk
```

Then,

```
X, Y, K = np.meshgrid(x, y, k)
# sum over k after evaluating f_k
f = fk(X, Y, K).sum(axis=-1) 

f.shape
# (100, 100)
```

Finally,

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X[...,0], Y[...,0], f)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, f)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly how I imagined it'd look if someone who knew what he was doing did it. Excellent :)