# Using other data with a function of the form f(x,y) = f(x,y,z).sum(axis=-1)

Tags: python, lambda

So, in my previous question wflynny gave me a really neat solution ([Surface where height is a function of two functions, and a sum over the third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284897/surface-where-height-is-a-function-of-two-functions-and-a-sum-over-the-third)). I've got that part working for my simple version, but now I'm trying to improve on this.

Consider the following lambda function:

```
 x = np.arange(0,100, 0.1)
 y = np.sin(y);
 f = lambda xx: (xx-y[x=xx])**2
 values = f(x)
```

Now, in this scenario it works. In fact, the `[x=xx]` is trivial in the example. However, the example can be extended:

```
 x = np.arange(0,100, 0.1)
 z = np.sin(y);
 f = lambda xx, yy: ( (xx-z[x=xx])**2 + yy**2)**0.5
 y = np.arange(0,100,0.1)
 [xgrid, ygrid] = np.meshgrid(x,y);
 values = f(xgrid,ygrid)
```

In this case, the error `ValueError: boolean index array should have 1 dimension` is generated. This is because `z.shape` is different from `xgrid.shape`, I think.

Note that here, `y=np.sin(y)` is a simplification. It's not a function but an array of arbitrary values. We really need to go to that array to retrieve them.

I do not know what the proper way to implement this is. I am going to try some things, but I hope that somebody here will give me hints or provide me with the *proper* way to do this in Python.

EDIT: I originally thought  I had solved it by using the following:

```
retrieve = lambda pp: map(lambda pp: dataArray[pp==phiArray][0], phi)
```

However, this merely returns the `dataArray`. Suppose `dataArray` contains a number of 'maximum' values for the polar radius. Then, you would normally incorporate this by saying something like `g = lambda xx, yy: f(xx,yy) * Heaviside( dataArray - radius(xx,yy))`. Then g would properly be zero if the radius is too large.

However, this doesn't work. I'm not fully sure but the behaviour seems to be something like taking a single value of `dataArray` instead of the entire array.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Sadly, this stuff has to work and I can't spend more time on making it nice. Therefore, I've opted for the dirty implementation. The actual thing I was interested in would be of the sort as the `g = lambda xx, yy` written above, so I can implement that directly (dirty) instead of nicely (without nested for loops).

```
def envelope(xx, yy):
    value = xx * 0.
    for i in range(0,N): #N is defined somewhere, and xx.shape = (N,N)
        for j in range(0,N):
            if ( dataArray[x=xx[i,j]][0] > radius(xx[i,j],yy[i,j])):
                value[i,j] = 1.
            else:
                value[i,j] = 0.
    return value
```

A last resort, but it works. And, sometimes results matter over writing good code, especially when there's a deadline coming up (and you are the only one that cares about good code).

I would still be very much interested in learning how to do this properly, if there is a proper way, and thus increase my fluency in clean Python.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My apologies, I thought that was clear. Edited.